# Ubuntu 22.04 on Gigabyte X670E Aorus Master - 5.1 sound not working

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm running the following setup and it's not possible to get 5.1 sound to work. Only front/left and front/right speakers are working. I've checked the settings already within the GUI and the CLI. Both shows 5.1 enabled, but the test sound gives exactly nothing on the other speakers.

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04 (Kernel 6.5)
- Board: Gigabyte X670E Aorus Master
- GPU: only iGPU(NO dedicated GPU)
- Sound+Video: via HDMI

Any Ideas?

alsa-info output:
https://pastebin.com/nS4xVPWu